# What is the use of NSCoder in initWithCoder:? (Cocoa and Cocoa Touch)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, serialization, nscoder

Whats the role of NSCoder here?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

`NSCoder` holds the state you saved the archive representation of the instance to initialize in `-[id<NSCoding> encodeWithCoder:]`.

In other words, you encoded an instance of self at one point in time, now you need the coder's info to restore your state.

Answer (score 0):

NSCoder handles archiving, most particularly in this typical case of a view, the archiving of a NIB. So when you `initWithCoder` the NIB is loaded, with the interface you've constructed in Interface Builder.

You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html